# Using Font Awesome in XSLTForms

Tags: font-awesome, xsltforms

I tryed to use Font Awesome in XSLTForms but no sucess. I included a link in the header, but every time I try to use an icon, it is not shown. Other CSS styles contained in different files work, but even if I include a  tags at the beggining and at the end of the file (for pre-processor) it doesnt work.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in xforms header and remove the `<css></css>` tags at the beggining and at the end of the file (for pre-processor)

```
<?css-conversion no?>
```